# How to use two separate payloads as parameters with Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
payload1 = {"action":"launch","network":"DMZ","name":"Testing1"}
           
payload2 = {"action":"launch","network":"Internal","name":"Testing2"}
           
r = requests.post("url", 
    params=(payload1,payload2), 
    headers=headers,
```

This is the latest code I've tried but I get error "ValueError: too many values to unpack". I've also tried putting both key:value pairs in one payload. The initial goal is to run two separate scans in two different networks.

How can this be done?

This will eventually expand across many networks, so best practice advise would also be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you would need to make a separate request per payload.

Comment: The API is designed to accept payload in a specific way with specific type only, so you have to check if it would accept multiple payloads